# How can I call variable inside anonymous function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have an question about how to call a variable inside annoymous function in node.js.

```
const client = require('cheerio-httpcli');

const url = 'https://puppetron.now.sh/render?url=https://festa.io/events';

client.fetch(url, (err, $, res) => {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  const firstItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)';
  const secondItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2)';
  const thirdItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3)';
  const fourthItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4)';
  const fifthItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1)';
  const sixthItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2)';
  const seventhItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3)';
  const eighthItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(4)';

  $(firstItem).each(function(post) {
    firstItemName = $(this).text()
  });
});

console.log(client.fetch.firstItem)
```

In this code, I want to console log the firstItemName outside of client.fetch.

First, I tried to console.log client.fetch.firstItem, but It didn't worked.

How can I call firstItemName variable outside of client.fetch?

Comment: in the code you posted `firstitemName` will be a global variable ... so it'll be just `firstItemName` - though it won't be populated "syncrhonously" so you'll need to wait for `client.fetch` to finish before trying to access it

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi :D Thanks for your help. I tried to ```console.log(firstItemName)``` but it just returned undefined error. I want to console.log it syncrhonously. Is there actually other way to do this? Actually what I'm making is crawl that data and turn that data to api with json format.

Comment: of course it's undefined ... the client.fetch callback hasn't run yet - you'll need to learn how to deal with asynchrony

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to define your firstItem cons inside your function?  Why not just define it outside of the scope of the anonymous function. this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679212/access-a-variable-inside-a-function-which-is-inside-a-function-in-javascript may provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async/await or Promises to handle async functions.

e.g in pseudo code.

```
const client = require('cheerio-httpcli');
const url = 'https://puppetron.now.sh/render?url=https://festa.io/events';

async function fetchItems(url) {
  client.fetch(url, (err, $, res) => {
  if(err){
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    return;
  }

  const firstItem = '#root > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.Responsive__DesktopView-yfth06-0.jdVFLa > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)';

    $(firstItem).each(function(post) {
      firstItemName = $(this).text()
    });
  });

  return firstItem;
}


//then you use the async function and wait until its done with processing your query.
const firstItem = await fetchItems(url);
console.log(firstItem );

//If u want to log out more properties/variables then you can return an object from the 
function with mapped variables.
```